# How can i retrive my image from sql server 2008 using matlab

Tags: sql-server, matlab

i had inserted image in sql server using matlab but when i am retrieving that image i get this
[845941x1 int8] as my output so please tell me how will i get my original image using this output........ or any other way to retrieve that image....

this is my code to insert image:

```
 // conn = database('test','prashant','');
 //pes = exec(conn,'insert into filee select ''jpg'' as filetype,* from          
 //openrowset  (bulk  ''D:\file\index.jpg'' , single_blob) as x ');
 //close(conn);
```

code to retrieve is:

```
// conn = database('test','prashant','');
// pess = exec(conn,'select * from filee');
//pess = fetch(pess);
// pess.data[1,3];
// close(conn);
```

please tell me the code to retrieve my image back.....

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you want, if you want to get the information from a table, perhaps something like this can do the trick:

```
exec(conn,'select * from filee')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this vector is the raw database representation of the image... Try to reshape it to it's original size and then to draw it:

```
image(reshape(int8array,height,width));
```

But since I just see that your dimension of the int8 array is a prime number I wonder whether it can be reshaped in an image...